# How to print the array element values in array order?

Tags: perl

How to print the array's values in order of array element?

```
@ab= <DATA>;
print "@ab\n";
@a = qw(a b c d);
foreach $s(@ab){
   foreach $m (@a){
        $z =~m/$m/g;
        print "$z";
    }
}
__DATA__
d 43
a 5
b 24
d 4
a 12
b 54
c 11
a 1
d 1
a 32
```

In this program gives outputs but i expect the outputs is

```
a 5
a 12
a 1
a 32
b 24
b 54
c 11
d 43
d 4
d 1
```

First prints the first array element's matching value then second and so on.. How can i do this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: print the matching value of the array elements. When print the all array matching data of the 'a' then print next array matching data 'b' and so on.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use a loop or do you just want to print the sorted values?

Answer (score 5):

Your outer loop should loop over `@a` and inner over `@ab`

```
my @ab= <DATA>;
my @a = qw(a b c d);

foreach my $m (@a) {
   foreach my $s (@ab) {
        print $s if $s =~ /^$m/;
    }
}
__DATA__
d 43
a 5
b 24
d 4
a 12
b 54
c 11
a 1
d 1
a 32
```

output

```
a 5
a 12
a 1
a 32
b 24
b 54
c 11
d 43
d 4
d 1
```

Comment: Bonus: This reduces the number of regex compilations from 40 to 4.

Comment: But it's still O(S*ID) when it could be O(S). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24984551/589924) for a solution that scales better.

Comment: @jaypal tnx, nice to be back.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to sort the array alphabetically but only based on the first letter. I think this does what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print sort { (substr $a, 0, 1) cmp (substr $b, 0, 1) } <DATA>;

__DATA__
d 43
a 5
b 24
d 4
a 12
b 54
c 11
a 1
d 1
a 32
```

Output:

```
a 5
a 12
a 1
a 32
b 24
b 54
c 11
d 43
d 4
d 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the sections, and then print

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %group;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($key) = split ' ';
    push @{$group{$key}}, $_;
}

for my $key (sort keys %group) {
    print @{$group{$key}};
}

__DATA__
d 43
a 5
b 24
d 4
a 12
b 54
c 11
a 1
d 1
a 32
```

Outputs:

```
a 5
a 12
a 1
a 32
b 24
b 54
c 11
d 43
d 4
d 1
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? It seems to answer the question

Comment: Because I misunderstood the problem in the first 5 minutes of waking up, and someone as a quick trigger.  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@ab= <DATA>;                                                                    
@a = qw(a b c d);                                                               

print map { $tmp = $_; grep { $tmp eq (split(" ", $_))[0] } @ab } @a;           

__DATA__                                                                        
d 43                                                                            
a 5                                                                             
b 24                                                                            
d 4                                                                             
a 12                                                                            
b 54                                                                            
c 11                                                                            
a 1                                                                             
d 1                                                                             
a 32
```

**Explanation**

- `map { ... } @a`: loop through each element in array `@a`, orderly.
- `$tmp = $_`: save the current value of `$_` of `map` function to variable `$tmp`.
- `grep { $tmp eq (split(" ", $_))[0] } @ab`: with each element in array `@ab`, we split it to get only the first character, compare with current `$tmp` value. If equal, grep return that element.

Answer (score 0):

This scales better than Сухой27's answer: O(S) instead of O(ID*S).

```
my @ids = qw( a b c d );

my %s_by_id;
while (my $s = <DATA>) {
    my ($id) = $s =~ /^(\S+)/
       or next;

    push @{ $s_by_id{$id} }, $s;
}

for my $id (@ids) {
   print @{ $s_by_id{$id} } if $s_by_id{$id};
}
```

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, fixed. (`[]` doesn't escape `$`)